# sender_dependant_default_transport_maps not being used by postfix

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

### Intent

We are trying to use the `sender_dependent_default_transport_maps` feature of postfix to use different SMTP relays based on the `from` address of a mail.
The goals are:

- allow our partners to use their own domain name as `from` email address for automated messages (e.g. `noreply@partner1.com`)
- make sure that emails sent from `noreply@partner1.com` actually reach their users (e.g. `user1@partner1.com`)

### Current configuration

Our current configuration is working fine but only uses our own SMTP server.

The `/etc/postfix/master.cf` is simple and looks like:

```
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (no)    (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
```

The `/etc/postfix/main.cf` is the following:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file=<path to PEM>
smtpd_tls_key_file=<path to KEY>
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = appserver.provider.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = $myhostname, appserver, localhost.localdomain, , localhost
relayhost = mail.provider.com:465
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl/passwd
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter =
smtp_sasl_security_options =
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtp_tls_wrappermode = yes
smtp_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/canonical_maps
sender_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_canonical_maps
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

### Attempted configuration

I tried the following configuration in order to achieve the goal.

- Update the `main.cf`:

  - remove the line `relayhost = mail.provider.com:465`
  - add a line `sender_dependant_default_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_dependant_default_transport.map`
- Add a `/etc/postfix/sender_dependant_default_transport.map` with the following content:

  ```
  @partner1.com     : smtp.partner1.com
  @provider.com     : mail.provider.com:465
  ```
- generate the map db: `sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sender_dependant_default_transport.map`
- restart the service: `sudo service postfix restart`

### Outcome

#### Sending from `@provider.com` to `@provider.com`

The email does not get sent:

```
postfix/smtpd[3011]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
postfix/smtpd[3011]: 3BE61178E1E: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
postfix/cleanup[3032]: 3BE61178E1E: message-id=<20181016075730.3BE61178E1E@appserver.provider.com>
postfix/qmgr[2997]: 3BE61178E1E: from=<provider@provider.com>, size=376, nrcpt=1 (queue active) postfix/smtp[3033]: connect to mx2.provider.com[<IPv6>]:25: Network is unreachable
postfix/smtp[3033]: SSL_connect error to mx1.provider.com[<IPv4>]:25:
postfix/smtp[3033]: warning: TLS library problem: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:794: postfix/smtp[3033]: 3BE61178E1E: Cannot start TLS: handshake failure postfix/smtp[3033]: SSL_connect error to mx2.provider.com[<IPv4>]:25: -1 postfix/smtp[3033]: warning: TLS library problem: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:794:
postfix/smtp[3033]: 3BE61178E1E: Cannot start TLS: handshake failure
postfix/smtp[3033]: SSL_connect error to mx3.provider.com[<IPv4>]:25:
postfix/smtp[3033]: warning: TLS library problem: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:794: postfix/smtp[3033]: 3BE61178E1E: Cannot start TLS: handshake failure postfix/smtp[3033]: connect to mx1.provider.com[<IPv6>]:25: Network is unreachable
postfix/smtp[3033]: 3BE61178E1E: to=<provider@provider.com>, relay=none, delay=19, delays=18/0.01/0.54/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to mx1.provider.com[<IPv6>]:25: Network is unreachable)
```

#### Sending from `@partner1.com` to `@provider.com`

The email does not get sent:

```
postfix/smtpd[3237]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
postfix/smtpd[3237]: 6234B178E1E: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
postfix/cleanup[3252]: 6234B178E1E: message-id=<20181016081109.6234B178E1E@appserver.provider.com>
postfix/qmgr[2997]: 6234B178E1E: from=<noreply@partner1.com>, size=368, nrcpt=1 (queue active) postfix/smtp[3253]: connect to mx3.provider.com[<IPv6>]:25: Network is unreachable
postfix/smtp[3253]: SSL_connect error to mx2.provider.com[<IPv4>]:25: -1
postfix/smtp[3253]: warning: TLS library problem: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:794: postfix/smtp[3253]: 6234B178E1E: Cannot start TLS: handshake failure postfix/smtp[3253]: connect to mx1.provider.com[<IPv6>]:25: Network is unreachable
postfix/smtp[3253]: SSL_connect error to mx3.provider.com[<IPv4>]:25: -1
postfix/smtp[3253]: warning: TLS library problem: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:794: postfix/smtp[3253]: 6234B178E1E: Cannot start TLS: handshake failure postfix/smtp[3253]: connect to mx2.provider.com[<IPv6>]:25: Network is unreachable
postfix/smtp[3253]: 6234B178E1E: to=<provider@provider.com>, relay=none, delay=16, delays=16/0.01/0.33/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to mx2.provider.com[<IPv6>]:25: Network is unreachable)
```

### Actual question

Sorry for the very long introduction but I wanted to make sure I was thorough.

It seems that:

- the config change in the `main.cf` was picked up because postfix does not try to use the default relay anymore `mail.provider.com` but defaults to the MX records
- The `sender_dependant_default_transport_maps` is not used at all

How to make sure it is actually used?
Could it be another cause?

---

According to the postfix logs while restarting, the parameter is not used:

```
postfix[4582]: /usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: sender_dependant_default_transport_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/sender_dependant_default_transport_maps
```

but it does tell me why it is not used..

Answer (score 1):

It was finally just a typo:
`sender_dependant_default_transport_maps` doesn't exist
while the correct spelling is `sender_dependent_default_transport_maps`